# Does C# WinForms have a slider control?

Tags: c#, winforms, slider

Can someone guide me if C# WinForms has a slider control? I see WPF has it but it doesn't show up for me in WinForms what could be the problem?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

There's a [TrackBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.aspx) class that looks a little different, but might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks. Found it under 'All Windows Form Controls'.

Here is a good guide for starting off with the TrackBar: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/trackbar-in-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 3):

Check out [MAC_Slider](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/MAC_Slider.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding "true" to the autoscroll property in a form or panel, this enables a scroll Bar to scroll between the content

Answer (score 0):

I found [this one](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17395/Owner-drawn-trackbar-slider) on Codeproject friendly to use and very customizable. Below an example of slider done using this project (design is not up to date, sample only to show features).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for a better looking trackbar in C# winforms use [Siticone](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Siticone.Desktop.UI/) or [Guana](https://gunaui.com/). You can change the color of the trackbar and lots more hope this helps :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31553855)